# How to split a string every two characters then implement them in a four-square cipher?

Tags: regex, string, foursquare

I am trying to write an encyption method that takes a string and splits it after every two characters. For example the word `messages` would be `me` `ss` `ag` `es`.

Then take the first string, `me`, and find where `m` corresponds on a plain1 square while also finding where `e` also fits on plain2 square. I can assume the string is always even numbered. I already have a getPosition method that will return the coordinates given a string. This is what I have so far:

```
public String encrypt(String message) {
String[] splitMessage = message.split("(?<=\\G..)");
        for (int i =0; i < message.length(); i++)
        {
            int [] pos = plain1.getPos(splitMessage[i]);
        }
```

My problem is I need the `splitMessage[i]` to be a `char`

Comment: Please, do not invent an encryption. Even highly skilled, advanced people can fail miserably with that, as shown by [MAGENTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAGENTA). Chances are that if you do not know how to split an array at every two characters, you will do it wrong. Suggestion: learn to walk before you run.

Answer (score 1):

This method will split a `String` into `chunkSize` `String`s:

```
public static String[] splitIntoChunks(String s, int chunkSize)
{
    int numberOfChunks = (s.length() / chunkSize)
        + (s.length() % chunkSize > 0 ? 1 : 0);

    String[] chunks = new String[numberOfChunks];

    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < s.length(); i += chunkSize, k++) {
        chunks[k] = s.substring(i, Math.min(i + chunkSize, s.length()));
    }

    return chunks;
}
```

A simple test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitIntoChunks("messages", 2)));
}
```

Results in this output:

```
[me, ss, ag, es]
```